# in android, how to stack ScrollView and recycler view(or any other view that extends scrollview) with each other

Tags: android, layout, android-scrollview, android-recyclerview

In Android, how to stack ScrollView and recycler view (or any other view that extends scroll view) on top of each other, like combine them together, one on the top of the other, act like all the content are within the same scroll view? I have tried

```
<Linear>  
   <ScrollView></ScrollView>  
   <recycler></recycler>  
</Linear>
```

or one inside of the other, none of them works

Comment: You can try to use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html.
If use scrollView or recyclerview like above, I think you have to set a fixed size to them

Answer (score 0):

At first use **recyclerView** inside **ScrollView** or any scrollable make you to trouble but you can handle it.

you can find your answer [hear](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32420770/3086080) I think.