# Use RecyclerView inside ScrollView with flexible Recycler item height

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-recyclerview, scrollable

I want to know if there is any possible way to use **RecyclerView**?

Before this, I used RecyclerView with **fixed height** inside a **ScrollView** but this time I don't know the height of the item.

**Hint**: I read all question and solution on stack question before asking this question.

**update:** 
Some solution show how to scroll **RecyclerView** on its own but I want to show it expanded.

Comment: What is your issue ?

Comment: @OmarHassan I should use more than one **RecyclerView** inside a **ScrollView**. just it

Comment: non of the above help me... only that answer post here : [Recyclerview inside scrollview](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36979664/4240256)

Comment: @EsterOr what do you exactly want to do? I work on my problem about 2 week to. (I was not expert that time)

Comment: Just want to help others with similar problem... as I was....

Comment: you can try flexbox in recyclerview for flexible scroll http://yuvarockers.blogspot.in/2017/04/flexbox-inside-recyclerview-as.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I search for answer this question all over the world but I didn't found any direct answer for this popular question. At last I mixed some trick together and solved this problem!

My problem start when my boss asked me to use a **RecyclerView** inside a **ScrollView**, and as you know we cannot use two **Scrollable** objects inside each other except when we set or know **fix item height** for our **RecyclerView**. and this is the answer:

**Step 1:**
at first you should find your RecyclerView flexible item height and this is possible from your **RecyclerView>onBindViewHolder**

```
holder.itemView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int cellWidth = holder.itemView.getWidth();// this will give you cell width dynamically
            int cellHeight = holder.itemView.getHeight();// this will give you cell height dynamically

            dynamicHeight.HeightChange(position, cellHeight); //call your iterface hear
        }
    });
```

with this code you find your item height as them build and send the item height to your activity with **interface**.

for those friend who have problem with interface i leave interface code below that should write in Adapter.

```
public interface DynamicHeight {
    void HeightChange (int position, int height);
}
```

**Step 2:**
we found our item height so far and now we want to set height to our RecyclerView. first we should calculate the Summation of item height. in this step we do this by **BitMap**
first **implements** last step **interface** and write these code below inside your **Activity** or **Fragment** that define your **RecyclerView**:

```
@Override
public void HeightChange(int position, int height) {
    itemHeight.put(position, height);
    sumHeight = SumHashItem (itemHeight);

    float density = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float viewHeight = sumHeight * density;
    review_recyclerView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) sumHeight;

    int i = review_recyclerView.getLayoutParams().height;
}

int SumHashItem (HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap) {
    int sum = 0;

    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> myItem: hashMap.entrySet())  {
        sum += myItem.getValue();
    }

    return sum;
}
```

**Step 3:**
now we have the summation of your RecyclerView height. for last step we should just send the Interface that we write in last step to adapter with some code like this:

```
reviewRecyclerAdapter = new ReviewRecyclerAdapter(activity, reviewList, review_recyclerView, this);
```

when you **implement** interface, you should send it to your with your context that I use **this**.

Enjoy it

Comment: i cant figur it out...getting some errors..can you please provide full example with adapter class and recyclerview implementation

Comment: @HetalUpadhyay which part you have Error? this week i have not enough time to do this. but if you are not in hUrry I will do it for you

Comment: actually i am not getting any error but when i tried same code with horizontal recycler view it display nothing...so it will be grateful to you if you can provide a code that work fine in both case horizontal and vertical scrolling

Comment: @HetalUpadhyay may you explain what do you want to do? because I have some code to calculate how many item should be in a horizontal form with fix width

Comment: @HetalUpadhyay ok, got it. I try to do it on friday.
send me an email: ashkan.hematian@gmail.com

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i am using GridLayoutManager not Linear

Comment: thanx...worked perfectly for me just added android:fillViewport="true" to scrollview and it start working

Comment: seems like variable `viewHeight` is never used

Comment: This is far more complicated than is necessary.Look at @Bhunnu Baba's answer.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to just scrolling then you can use to **NestedScrollView** instead of ***ScrollView*** So you can modify your code with following :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            //design your content here with RecyclerView 

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView solved my issue, thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No ConstraintLayout, no custom subclasses. This just works as intended.

Answer (score 13):

Use This line to your recyclerview :

```
 android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

try it ,recyclerview will be smoothly scrolled with flexible height

Comment: just for records, it is available from API 21

Answer (score 8):

**[RESOLVED]** I have same issue with Horizontal recycleview.
Change Gradle repo for recycleview

```
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

Write this: `linearLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);`

Fixed bugs related to various measure-spec methods in update

Check http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-recyclerview

I have found issue with 23.2.1 library:
When item is match_parent recycle view fill full item to view, please always  go with `min height or "wrap_content".`

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

To fix fling in `RecyclerView` you must override `canScrollVertically` in `LinearLayoutManager`:

```
linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context) {
 @Override
 public boolean canScrollVertically() {
  return false;
 }
};
```

Comment: To add to this answer, you also need to use NestedScrollView this answer alone didn't work on Android 7+ :\

Answer (score 3):

I fully agree with Ashkan solution, big thanks (voted +1!), but there is one thing...

If RecyclerView does scroll correctly inside ScrollView/NestedScrollView BUT it doesn't fling (intercept it) then the solution is to extend RecyclerView and override OnInterceptTouchEvent and OnTouchEvent. If you don't need any click actions but just want to present items with working fling then simply return false in both like below:

```
public class InterceptingRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    public InterceptingRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public InterceptingRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public InterceptingRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or actually it should be called NonIntercepting... ;) Simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

In case setting fixed height for the RecyclerView didn't work for someone (like me), here is what I've added to the fixed height solution:

```
   mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        int action = e.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
});
```

I

Comment: I didn't test it yet, but I think your code want to scroll **RecyclerView** on it own. I will try it today.
tnx dear friend

Comment: i didn't help, as I said before it help to scroll RecyclerView on it own with fix height. it's not my goal.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`.

And for `RecyclerView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And in Code

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

When i put recyclerview inside flexboxlayout inside scrollview, like

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
  <LinearLayout
    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView />
    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

then `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` and `mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` doesn't work.

with this code I just get what needed

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                int action = e.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });
```