# RecyclerView not appearing using ScrollView inside an XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

Here is an XML, when I am using ScrollView `below_recycler_view` **RecyclerView** is not appearing, without using **ScrollView** inside an xml `below_recycler_view` appears

**So what could be the reason ?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_main" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/lind"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        .....

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lind"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        .....

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        .....

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        ......

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/below_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you cant put recyclerview or listview in scrollview. again scrollview only takes one direct child.

Comment: to use recyclerview inside scrollview you have to create your own layout manager check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420770/use-recyclerview-inside-scrollview-with-flexible-recycler-item-height

Comment: I am using two recyclerviews inside ScrollView - one horizontal and second vertical.. and the issue is it hides Vertical RecyclerView

Answer (score -1):

You can't put `ListView/RecycleView` inside `ScrollView`. When `ListView` and `RecycleView` trying to calculate their height, they are using parent height. `ScrollView` doesn't have a speciefed height, so it gives an error.