# ScrollView doesn't work in Android

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

I have a fragment that contains a view pager, a recycler view, etc. 
I want to place all of that inside a scroll view , but it just refuses to scroll. Am I missing something here?
I've tried setting fillViewport false, and removing the scrollbars:none, and a couple of other things but nothing helps..

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="abc"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_below="@id/headerLayout"
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:layout_below="@id/recyclerView"
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
                    android:id="@+id/pager_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"/>
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: there are two sets of scroll elements. `ScrollView` and `RecyclerView`. Try adding everything into `RecyclerView`, your problem will be solved. try this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/25960103/842607 . It explains everything required

Comment: recyclerview has it's own scrolling so they might be over lapping

Comment: @JimitPatel what do you mean add everything into a recyclerview? I can't just place all that (view pager ,existing recyclerview,etc.) into a recyclerView, which means another Adapter class to somehow handle all that.. Or I just didn't understand you correctly?

Comment: @BVtp, actually you can. I will post a code. I won't explain it, just crack it out as it is too long to explain.

Answer (score 0):

As I responded in comment, check the adapter class of `RecyclerView`. I won't be explaining it as it is too big to explain. But for starters follow the link [Recyclerview and handling different type of row inflation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation/25960103#25960103)

For the code below you can relate it with StyFi app from google store

```
    public class FeedRecyclerStickyHeaderAdapter<T> extends RecyclerStickyTypeWrapper<T>
                implements StickyRecyclerHeadersAdapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

            private static final String TAG = FeedRecyclerStickyHeaderAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

            public static final int VIEW_LOOK = 0;
            public static final int VIEW_PRODUCT = 1;
            public static final int VIEW_BLOG = 2;
            public static final int VIEW_BRAND = 3;
            public static final int VIEW_PROGRESS = 4;
            public static final int VIEW_AD = 5;
            public static final int VIEW_NEW_ARRIVALS = 6;
            public static final int VIEW_FEATURED_BRANDS = 7;

            public static final int VIEW_BIG_BANNER = 8;
            public static final int VIEW_BRAND_FEED = 9;

            private static final int TOTAL_VIEWS = 10;

            private OnInteractionListener listener;
            private OnButtonClickListener callback;
            private Fragment fragment;
            private Handler handler;
            private TimerTask task;

            private ArrayList<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> holderArrayList;

            public FeedRecyclerStickyHeaderAdapter(Activity context, @NonNull List<T> objects, @NonNull OnInteractionListener listener) {
                super();
                this.context = context;
                this.objects = objects;
                this.listener = listener;
                holderArrayList = new ArrayList<>(objects.size());
            }

            public FeedRecyclerStickyHeaderAdapter(Activity context, @NonNull List<T> objects, Fragment fragment,
                                                   @NonNull OnInteractionListener listener) {
                super();
                this.context = context;
                this.objects = objects;
                this.fragment = fragment;
                this.listener = listener;
            }

            /**
             * Used for feeds for adding products to wishlist
             *
             * @param context
             * @param objects
             * @param fragment
             * @param listener
             * @param callback
             */
            public FeedRecyclerStickyHeaderAdapter(Activity context, @NonNull List<T> objects, Fragment fragment,
                                                   @NonNull OnInteractionListener listener, @NonNull OnButtonClickListener callback) {
                super();
                this.context = context;
                this.objects = objects;
                this.fragment = fragment;
                this.listener = listener;
                this.callback = callback;
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                if (position > -1 && position < objects.size()) {
                    if (objects.get(position) instanceof Feed) {
                        switch (((Feed) objects.get(position)).getViewType()) {
                            case Feed.LOOK_VIEW:
                                return VIEW_LOOK;
                            case Feed.BLOG_VIEW:
                                return VIEW_BLOG;
                            case Feed.PRODUCT_VIEW:
                                return VIEW_PRODUCT;
                            case Feed.PROGRESS_VIEW:
                                return VIEW_PROGRESS;
                            case Feed.FEATURED_BRANDS_VIEW:
                                return VIEW_FEATURED_BRANDS;
                            case Feed.NEW_ARRIVAL_VIEW:
                                return VIEW_NEW_ARRIVALS;
                            case Feed.AD_VIEW:
                                return VIEW_AD;
                            case Feed.BRAND_VIEW:
                                return VIEW_BRAND;
                        }
                    } else if (objects.get(position) instanceof BrandFeed) {
                        switch (((BrandFeed) objects.get(position)).getViewType()) {
                            case BrandFeed.AD_VIEW:
                                return VIEW_AD;
                            case BrandFeed.BIG_BANNER_VIEW:
                                return VIEW_BIG_BANNER;
                            case BrandFeed.BRAND_FEED_VIEW:
                                return VIEW_BRAND_FEED;
                            case BrandFeed.PROGRESS_VIEW:
                                return VIEW_PROGRESS;
                        }
                    } else if (objects.get(position) instanceof Looks) {
                        if (null != ((Looks) objects.get(position)).getLookId())
                            return VIEW_LOOK;
                        else
                            return VIEW_PROGRESS;
                    } else if (null == objects.get(position))
                        return VIEW_PROGRESS;
                }
                return super.getItemViewType(position);
            }

            @Override
            public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View v;
                switch (viewType) {
                    case VIEW_LOOK: {
                        ViewHolderLook holder = new ViewHolderLook(LayoutInflater.from(context)
                                .inflate(R.layout.listitem_look, parent, false));
                        if (2 <= context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.gridviewcolumn)) {
                            initializeHeaders(holder.view, holder);
                        }
                        return holder;
                    }
                    case VIEW_PRODUCT: {
                        ViewHolderProduct holder = new ViewHolderProduct(LayoutInflater.from(context)
                                .inflate(R.layout.listitem_new_product, parent, false));
                        if (2 <= context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.gridviewcolumn)) {
                            initializeHeaders(holder.view, holder);
                        }
                        return holder;
                    }
                    case VIEW_BLOG: {
                        ViewHolderBlog holder = new ViewHolderBlog(LayoutInflater.from(context)
                                .inflate(R.layout.blog_list_item_new, parent, false));
                        if (2 <= context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.gridviewcolumn)) {
                            initializeHeaders(holder.view, holder);
                        }
                        return holder;
                    }
                    case VIEW_BRAND: {
                        ViewHolderBrands holder = new ViewHolderBrands(LayoutInflater.from(context)
                                .inflate(R.layout.listitem_feed_brand, parent, false));
                        if (2 <= context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.gridviewcolumn)) {
                            initializeHeaders(holder.view, holder);
                        }
                        return holder;
                    }
                    case VIEW_PROGRESS: {
                        v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_progress, parent, false);
                        return new ViewHolderProgress(v);
                    }
                    case VIEW_AD: {
                        v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listitem_offers, parent, false);
                        return new ViewHolderAd(v);
                    }
                    case VIEW_NEW_ARRIVALS: {
                        v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listitem_new_arrivals, parent, false);
                        return new ViewHolderNewArrivals(v);
                    }
                    case VIEW_FEATURED_BRANDS: {
                        v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listitem_featured_brands, parent, false);
                        return new ViewHolderFeaturedBrands(v);
                    }
                    case VIEW_BRAND_FEED: {
                        v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listitem_brandfeed, parent, false);
                        return new ViewHolderBrandFeed(v);
                    }
                    case VIEW_BIG_BANNER: {
                        v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listitem_brandfeed_big_banner, parent, false);
                        return new ViewHolderBigBanner(v);
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + position);
                if (null != holder) {
                    if (holder instanceof ViewHolderLook) {
                        if (2 <= context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.gridviewcolumn)) {
                            setHeadersData((ViewHolderLook<T>) holder, position);
                        }
                        bindLookView((ViewHolderLook<T>) holder, position);
                    } else if (holder instanceof ViewHolderProduct) {
                        if (2 <= context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.gridviewcolumn)) {
                            setHeadersData((ViewHolderProduct<T>) holder, position);
                        }
                        bindProductView((ViewHolderProduct<T>) holder, position);
                    } else if (holder instanceof ViewHolderBlog) {
                        if (2 <= context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.gridviewcolumn)) {
                            setHeadersData((ViewHolderBlog<T>) holder, position);
                        }
                        bindBlogView((ViewHolderBlog<T>) holder, position);
                    } else if (holder instanceof ViewHolderBrands) {
                        if (2 <= context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.gridviewcolumn)) {
                            setHeadersData((ViewHolderBrands<T>) holder, position);
                        }
                        bindBrand((ViewHolderBrands<T>) holder, position);
                    } else if (holder instanceof ViewHolderAd)
                        bindAd((ViewHolderAd<T>) holder, position);
                    else if (holder instanceof ViewHolderNewArrivals)
                        bindNewArrival((ViewHolderNewArrivals<T>) holder, position);
                    else if (holder instanceof ViewHolderFeaturedBrands)
                        bindFeaturedBrands((ViewHolderFeaturedBrands<T>) holder, position);
                    else if (holder instanceof ViewHolderProgress) {
                        if (2 == context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.gridviewcolumn)) {
                            StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
                            layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
                            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        }
                    } else if (holder instanceof ViewHolderBigBanner) {
                        bindBigBanner((ViewHolderBigBanner<T>) holder, position);
                    } else if (holder instanceof ViewHolderBrandFeed) {
                        bindBrandFeed((ViewHolderBrandFeed<T>) holder, position);
                    }

                    if (null == holderArrayList)
                        holderArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                    if (null != objects && position != -1 && position < objects.size()) {
                        if (position < holderArrayList.size() || position == 0)
                            holderArrayList.add(position, holder);
                        else
                            holderArrayList.add(holder);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public long getHeaderId(int position) {
                if (2 <= context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.gridviewcolumn))
                    return -1;

                switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
                    case VIEW_PROGRESS:
                    case VIEW_AD:
                    case VIEW_NEW_ARRIVALS:
                    case VIEW_FEATURED_BRANDS:
                    case VIEW_BIG_BANNER:
                    case VIEW_BRAND_FEED:
                        return -1;
                    default:
                        return getItem(position).hashCode();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return getItem(position).hashCode();
            }

            @Override
            public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateHeaderViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {

                StickyHeaderViewHolder<T> holder = new StickyHeaderViewHolder<T>(LayoutInflater.from(context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.listitem_header, parent, false));
                initializeHeaders(holder.view, holder);
                return holder;
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "onBindHeaderViewHolder: " + position);

                if (viewHolder instanceof StickyHeaderViewHolder) {
                    setHeadersData((StickyHeaderViewHolder) viewHolder, position);
                }
            }

            /**
             * Overloading function for setting headers for tabs for sticky headers
             *
             * @param holder
             * @param position
             */
            private void setHeadersData(StickyHeaderViewHolder holder, int position) {
                holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    // This click listener is not working as sticky headers are just canvas and not views
                    // as desired for click listeners.
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (null != v.getTag()) {
                            if (v.getTag() instanceof Looks) {
                                Looks data = (Looks) v.getTag();
                                openLook(data);
                            } else if (v.getTag() instanceof Brand) {
                                Brand data = (Brand) v.getTag();
                                openBrand(data.getBrandId(), data.getBrandName());
                            } else if (v.getTag() instanceof Product) {
                                Product data = (Product) v.getTag();
                                openBrand(data.getBrandId(), data.getBrandName());
                            } else if (v.getTag() instanceof Blog) {
                                Blog data = (Blog) v.getTag();

                            }

                        }
                    }
                });

                final T type = getItem(position);
                if (type instanceof Feed) {
                    Feed object = (Feed) type;
                    switch (object.getViewType()) {
                        case Feed.LOOK_VIEW: {
                            Looks data = object.getLook();
                            holder.imgHeaderDp.setImageUrl(data.getStylistImage(), MyApp.getInstance().getImageLoader());
                            holder.lblHeaderName.setText(data.getStylistName());
                            holder.lblHeaderTime.setText(TimeConversions.longToPrettyTimeString(data.getCreatedDate()));

                            holder.lblHeaderTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.view.setTag(data);
                            break;
                        }
                        case Feed.BLOG_VIEW: {
                            Blog data = object.getBlog();
        //                    holder.imgHeaderDp.setImageUrl(data.getThumb(), MyApp.getInstance().getImageLoader());
                            holder.lblHeaderName.setText(data.getAuthorName());
                            holder.lblHeaderTime.setText(TimeConversions.longToPrettyTimeString(data.getPostedDate()));
        //
                            holder.lblHeaderTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.view.setTag(data);
                            break;
                        }
                        case Feed.PRODUCT_VIEW: {
                            Product data = object.getProduct();
        //                    holder.imgHeaderDp.setImageUrl(data.getProductThumbnail(), MyApp.getInstance().getImageLoader());
                            holder.lblHeaderName.setText(data.getBrandName());

                            holder.lblHeaderTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.view.setTag(data);
                            break;
                        }
                        case Feed.BRAND_VIEW: {
                            Brand data = object.getBrand();
                            holder.imgHeaderDp.setImageUrl(data.getImgLogoUrl(), MyApp.getInstance().getImageLoader());
                            holder.lblHeaderName.setText(data.getBrandName());
                            holder.lblHeaderTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.view.setTag(data);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (objects.get(position) instanceof Looks) {
                    if (null != ((Looks) objects.get(position)).getLookId()) {
                        // Looks in Looks feed
                        Looks data = ((Looks) objects.get(position));
                        holder.imgHeaderDp.setImageUrl(data.getStylistImage(), MyApp.getInstance().getImageLoader());
                        holder.lblHeaderName.setText(data.getStylistName());
                        holder.lblHeaderTime.setText(TimeConversions.longToPrettyTimeString(data.getCreatedDate()));

                        holder.lblHeaderTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.view.setTag(data);
                    }
                }
            }
    class ViewHolderLook<T> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            // Header
            RoundedNetworkImageView imgHeaderDp;
            FontTextView lblHeaderName;
            FontTextView lblHeaderTime;
            View view;

            // Body
            FontTextView lblLookName, lblLookDesc;
            CustomCheckbox chkFavorite;
            ImageView btnShare;
            SquareNetworkImageView imgLook;

            public ViewHolderLook(View view) {
                super(view);

                chkFavorite = (CustomCheckbox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk_favorite);
                btnShare = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
                imgLook = (SquareNetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_look);
                lblLookName = (FontTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lbl_title);
                lblLookDesc = (FontTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lbl_desc);

                // if it's tab then only initialize else not required
                if (2 <= context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.gridviewcolumn)) {
                    this.view = view.findViewById(R.id.header);
                }
            }
        }

    class ViewHolderBlog<T> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            // Header
            RoundedNetworkImageView imgHeaderDp;
            FontTextView lblHeaderName;
            FontTextView lblHeaderTime, lblReadFull;
            View view;
            View shareView, root;
            LinearLayout llShare;
            FontTextView lblBlogTitle, lblAuthor, lblRead, lblTime, lblDescription, lblLookCount;
            FontButton btnCopyToClipboard, btnWhatsApp, btnEmail, btnFacebook, btnTwitter, btnGPlus, btnPinterest, btnInstagram;
            SquareNetworkImageView imgBlog;
            CustomNetworkImageView blog_image;
            ImageView chkShare;

            public ViewHolderBlog(View view) {
                super(view);

                lblBlogTitle = (FontTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.blog_title);
                lblDescription = (FontTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.blog_description);
                lblLookCount = (FontTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lbl_looks_count);
                lblAuthor = (FontTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_author);
                imgBlog = (SquareNetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_blogimage);
                lblRead = (FontTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_read);
                lblTime = (FontTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_timer);
                llShare = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_share_container);
                chkShare = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.share);
                blog_image = (CustomNetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.blog_image);
                lblReadFull = (FontTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.read_full);
                this.root = view;

                // if it's tab then only initialize else not required
                if (2 <= context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.gridviewcolumn)) {
                    this.view = view.findViewById(R.id.header);
                }
            }
        }

    class ViewHolderAd<T> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            protected CustomViewPager viewPager;
            protected LinearLayout llPage;

            public ViewHolderAd(View view) {
                super(view);
                viewPager = (CustomViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
                llPage = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_page);
            }
        }
    .
    .
    .
    .

}
```

And this is the layout for the first Feed screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/lookforu_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.mycompany.myapp.app.custom.widget.GifSwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <view
            android:id="@+id/grid_view"
            class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/half_padding"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </com.mycompany.myapp.app.custom.widget.GifSwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is there really no easier way to make this scrollview work?

Comment: if that means that much then try this link - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32532511/842607. But I personally prefer to have everything inside `RecyclerView`

Comment: if I change RecyclerView to ListView, would that help?

Comment: Same answer. Recycler view or list view

Comment: I've erased the recycler view. but the scroll views still doesn't work.. maybe the recycler view is not the issue? (or not the only issue ,at the very least)